# Safely Pause/Resume Remote UIWebView WebSockets when the app enters Background/Active states

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, websocket

My app is primarily a full screen UIWebView. It does not currently have any method implemented to handle pausing/resuming the WebSockets activity inside the UIWebView.

In theory my app could stop the WebView from doing everything, and simply refresh the page? I don't know if that's the best method though, which is why I'm here.

The app crashes whenever I press the physical Home button, wait a while, and attempt to resume the app by pressing the App Icon and going into it. The app will usually just crash and resume back to the Home Screen again. When I tap the App Icon again the app starts over fresh like it was just opened for the first time after startup of the device.

During the crash I see things in the debug information like...

> Thread 7 WebThread: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5)
>
> void std::_*1::*_push_heap_front(WebCore::TimerHeapIterator,
>   WebCore::TimerHeapIterator, WebCore::TimerHeapLessThanFunction&,
>   std::__1::iterator_traits::difference_type)
>   + 194

I'm not sure what to do, I obviously have nothing setup in my app delegate for "applicationDidEnterBackground" or "applicationDidBecomeActive" or any of the other states, as I'm not sure what is the best method to somehow "pause" the content and "resume" it, or even HOW to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop it in JS.

From ObjC, listen to the app state change event (**UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification** or **UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification**).

Inside the callback, you'll call **stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString** to stop your websockets.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willResignActive) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];

-(void)willResignActive
{
    [m_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"stopWS();"];    // stopWS is implemented in JS
}
```