# iOS App Crashes - I suspect it has to do with UIWebView using WebSockets

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, websocket

I am not currently using applicationWillResignActive / applicationWillEnterForeground or anything similar, as I'm not sure exactly how to handle this issue I'm running into.

My app keeps crashing if I open it up, press home screen, wait about 5 minutes, and try to go back into the app again.

The app is mainly a UIWebView that loads a node.js powered websocket, so I think that is the culprit.

How can I stop the UIWebView from doing anything/everything when the user leaves the app (applicationWillResignActive is what I'm guessing needs to be used). I have played with a half dozen ideas and I cannot for the life of me get the app to stop crashing.

My Current Idea:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaulCenter] postNotificationName:@"EnterBackground" object:Nil userInfo: Nil];
}
```

...and then from there I edit my ViewController.m file to do something to the UIWebView on that page. The problem is, what will stop the UIWebView from doing anything while in the background? I have tried stoploading, and for some reason had no success, or it would still crash.

Comment: Are you customizing the NSUrlProtocol? and doing some thing like registerClass in your webView Controller? post your crash log or web view codes.

Comment: Could you find the reason why your app crash?

Comment: Show the stack trace for the crash.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't reproduce the exact issue (`WebThread: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5)`—taken from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915930/safely-pause-resume-remote-uiwebview-websockets-when-the-app-enters-background-a)), but I did notice that the WebSocket messages were being buffered, so it maybe that if you leave the app in the background long enough, you will hit a memory pressure issue that may be the cause of this crash.

However, in the process of researching this question I did manage to make the app reliably crash with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` originating from the `WebThread` so I'll post the details here in the hope it may be of use to you or someone else.

> For the purposes of this question, my WebSocket server simply broadcast the time every second to any connected clients.

As I mentioned, I had noticed that the UIWebView was buffering the WebSocket messages when the app was backgrounded. To prevent this, I wanted to close the WebSocket connection when the app was moved into the background.

In my view controller hosting the UIWebView, I registered a selector for `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and in that selector, I called a JavaScript function in my web page that called `close` on the WebSocket object.

**ViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(appWillResignActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)appWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"closeWebSocket();"];
}
```

**Web Page:**

```
function closeWebSocket() {
    socket.close(); // socket is an instance of WebSocket
    socket = undefined;
}
```

I wanted the WebSocket to reconnect when the app was moved back into the foreground, so I registered another selector, this time for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and in that selector called another function that would initialise the WebSocket connection.

**ViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(appWillResignActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)appWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"closeWebSocket();"];
}

- (void)appDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"openWebSocket();"];
}
```

**Web Page:**

```
function openWebSocket() {  
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + document.location.host + "/ping");  

    socket.onopen = function () { console.log("Opened"); };
    socket.onmessage = function (message) { 
      var log = $('#log');
      log.html(message.data + '<br>' + log.html()); 
      console.log(message.data);
    };
    socket.onclose = function () { console.log("Closed"); };
}
```

Running the app, the WebSocket connection was established, messages were received, and the app moved into the background. After a few seconds, I brought the app back to the foreground (by tapping on the app icon) and the app crashed with an exception similar to `WebThread: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5`. The cause of this was the evaluation of the JavaScript call to `openWebSocket()` when the app was brought back to the foreground. Delaying the execution of `openWebSocket()` by a few milliseconds fixed the issue. By `appDidBecomeActive` method ended up looking like this:

```
- (void)appDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"setTimeout(openWebSocket, 5);"];
}
```

Running the app again, the WebSocket connection was established, messages received, and the app backgrounded. When I brought the app back into the foreground after few seconds later, the app did not crash and the messages started coming through WebSocket connection again.

Comment: Nice answer @neilco. One suggestion, could you not just use the pause/resume events in Javascript? They should translate nicely to appWillResignActive/appDidBecomeActive.